# Find and replace special character in URL - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am using the Google Maps iframe to generate a map on my website. The iframe looks like this:

```
<iframe id="googlemap" width="199" height="199" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=KEY&zoom=14&language=nb&q=Møllesvingen+2,0854+OSLO"></iframe>
```

If you see the attribute `src` you see that there is the special character 'ø' which I would like to replace with `%C3%B8` (UTF-8 Bytes).

I have tried it with several replace-functions but nothing seem to work. 
Here is what I am trying right now:

```
var src;

src = $('#googlemap').attr('src');

src.replace('ø', '%C3%B8');
```

But it isn't working. Hope somebody can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is the `src` being set initially? It would be far better to change it there than to plaster over the cracks with JS

Comment: You need to reset `src` property use `$('#googlemap').attr('src', function(_,src){return src.replace('ø', '%C3%B8');});`

Comment: have you considered `escape()`, `encodeURI()` or somesuch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add encoding.
Try this,

```
src = $('#googlemap').attr('src');
src = encodeURI(src);
$('#googlemap').attr('src', src);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replace(/[ø]/g,'%C3%B8');
```

use regular expression to solve it. The above code will replace the special character.

Comment: There's no need to complicate the things here. `encodeURI` does the job very well.

Answer (score 0):

It does actually. The `replace` function return a new string. Store new string into variable and change the src back.

```
var src;
var newStr;

src = $('#googlemap').attr('src');

newStr = src.replace('ø', '%C3%B8');

console.log(src);
console.log(newStr);

$('#googlemap').attr('src', newStr);
```